# What is blocking: Firewall and tcpwrapper?

Tags: networking, iptables, tcp-wrappers

Is it possible to find whether the firewall (iptables) or tcpwrapper is blocking a connection without accessing the remote server? (Maybe with tcpdump?)

Comment: A firewall on your side, or on the remote side? I.e., can you log into the firewall?

Comment: Remote side. The scenario is like I am not able to log into the remote server anyway. (Not a real scenario, I am trying to learn).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IP network layer doesn't know if a `tcpwrapper` is blocking the connection. Even when `tcpwrapper` blocks, the network port will appear as "open". Example with `sshd` being blocked via [hosts_access](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man5/hosts_access.5.html):

```
$ nc -w1 -v -z host.example.org 1234
nc: host.example.org (192.168.0.130) 1234 [1234] open

$ ssh -p 1234 host.example.org
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
```

A IP based firewall on the other hand would (in most cases) block the connection on the network level and the port would appear as "closed".